# I am searching very Simple Auto Complete Search Users with display picture

Tags: jquery, html, search, autocomplete

I am searching a very simple auto complete search users with display picture, similar to facebook friend search, but that only displays picture and friend name in front of his picture.

Similar to:

[image]

Comment: And have you tried anything on your own, in case there's no software recommendation?

Comment: http://jsbin.com/cunuxaqe/2/edit?html,js,output

Comment: HI Thanks for your suggestion. 
Yes i have tried Auto Complete j query plugin but didn't found how to use Images in front of keywords. I need to show some static records. No backend related funtionality

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at Select2 plugin.

https://select2.github.io/examples.html

check the "Templating" example.

Answer (score 1):

1. You can use jquery ui:
2. You can write your own (that's pretty easy..)
3. There are many plugins which does it, there of them:

   - [TextExt](http://textextjs.com/manual/examples/autocomplete-with-custom-render.html)
   - [EasyAutocomplete](http://easyautocomplete.com/)
   - [autoComplete](https://goodies.pixabay.com/jquery/auto-complete/demo.html)